# Lightbox2 Not Working; "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or Unexpected Token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am attempting to use Lokesh Dhakar's Lightbox2 on my art portfolio site. I have downloaded the files, followed all instructions, and used the lightbox-plus-jquery.js file (since I know next to nothing about Jquery).

When I click the link to the image, it only opens the image up on a new page with a dark background.

I use Chrome, so I had it inspect the page, and it found a "Unexpected SyntaxError: Invalid or Unexpected Token", referring to "lightbox-plus-jquery.js:1".
I've never seen that error before.

Can someone please help and find out where I went wrong? This is driving me absolutely INSANE.

Site: http://art.juniebug.net/portfolio.html

Thank you!!

UPDATED CODE BELOW: 2/26/17 using CDNs now!:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html><head>
<meta name="Author" content="Janna Correa">


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style>
<!--
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: lightskyblue;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
 } 
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: lightskyblue;
}

-->
</style>
<title>JMC illustration * juniebug.net</title></head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="darkgreen" alink="orchid"   
vlink="mediumspringgreen">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, MS Reference Sans Serif, Calibri">




<br>
<br>
<center>

<br><br><br>


    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <center><img src="artinvisibar.gif"></center>


<br>
    <center>
    <img src="logo-jmc1.gif">
    </center>
    <br>


<center>
<img src="artstrip1.jpg">

    <br>
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="port/momo-Rio2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" rel="lightbox[closeup]"><img src="port/thumbs/momorio-t.gif" width="51" height="55"></a>

<a href="port/ioiosam2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" rel="lightbox[closeup]"><img src="port/thumbs/ioiosam-t.gif" width="51" height="55"></a>

</div>








</center>



    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Just did! Sorry about that, first-time poster here!

Comment: I wish I could get my coding to work like the fiddle you made!! How did you do that?
Do you think mine is still failing because I'm using the lightbox with jquery.js? Should I try the lightbox.js without the jquery?... I think I've already tried this though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the jquery plugin first** (you must load it first as your plugin will depend on it to work), then add your lightbox plugin.

**Like this**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

And also you should add the scripts just before the `</body>` tag or just before the `</head>` tag. But in the site you are adding it inside `</center>` tag.

**WORKING FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/ayan/dzpqucvc/

**UPDATE:** For the list of CDNs, you can find it [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lightbox2).

Answer (score 0):

You can try cdn provider for this. Or maybe I think you can try removing all comments in lightbox-plus-jquery.js file :))

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still does not work when I tried to use the provider link. :(
Removing all comments...? How would I do that?
(Thank you, though!)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it's clear that you haven't added jQuery link to your source code. Do it by either downloading and linking to it using `<script>` or use a CDN instead like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

So your JS code will look like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

**Note: The jQuery MUST be loaded before the LightboxJS.**

Cheers :-)

Comment: He used lightbox-plus file. So dont need add jquery, my friend. Yo can visit this link to refer: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started

Comment: Tried this-- it did not fix the problem. ;_;
Also, forgive me for not adding the code to my post-- I don't know how! Thank you, though!